# Get TimePicker Current Time on Button Click

Tags: android, android-timepicker

Friends 
I am new on Android App Developing. I have nearly completed my app.

In the last stage, I'm facing difficulties and trying for the last three days to solve it but could not.

I need to get the current hour and minutes from a time picker (without Dialog) when the user clicks a button. I want to save this data to a database on this button click.

Would you anybody please help me providing just an XML and JAVA file as below.

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.timepicker.MainActivity" >

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
package com.example.timepicker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Calendar instance you can get current hour and minutes-

```
Calendar c;
private int mhour;
private int mminute;
```

initialize -

```
c = Calendar.getInstance();
mhour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
mminute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

// you will get current hour and minutes of device time
```

Also refer this [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)